# Any manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ admits a Kähler deformation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

It is known that small deformations of a manifold $X$ in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ might no longer be in $\mathcal C$, see [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01459236) for example.

However, the following question is still open:

> For any $X$ in $\mathcal C$, does there always **exists** a deformation $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ of $X$, such that for any small neighborhood $U$ of $X$, there exists a Kähler deformation $X_t:=\pi^{-1}(t)$ with $t\in U$?

Does anyone has any counterexample?

Comment: I think this already fails for the non-projective, proper complex schemes of Hironaka in the appendix of Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry".

Comment: @JasonStarr , can you give more details?  In Hironaka's example, the central fiber of the family is a non-Kähler Moishezon manifold, and the nearby fibers are all projective. I don't see why it provides a counterexample.

Comment: You might mean a different example than I mean.  At any rate, every complex manifold that is bimeromorphic to a Kaehler manifold is in Fujiki class $\mathcal{C}$.